# it's okay 192MB JVM Heap Size for a java web system?

Tags: java, web, jvm

I'm implementing a java web system (with Apache Tomcat 8 hibernate, spring and mysql) and have given me the option of hosting with 192MB JVM Heap Size, the system makes simple queries and turnout will be around 50 people
okay that option?
PDT: Also I have another option that has JVM Heap Size 288MB but obviously more expensive.
Thank You

Comment: Depends on what your system does. But you can always start small and increase as required.

Comment: My system is basic(selects, delete and update querys) , at most send messages to gmail. 
But this well jvm to start?

Comment: Suck it and see but sounds like it will be fine for starters.

Comment: As long as your application passes your load tests, your okay.  But memory is cheap, 288MB is nothing

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst - Memory cheap, but if you are paying for hosting it can be tens of dollars extra a month.

Comment: thanks :) a last question its the same to test in my netbeans the jvm with-Xmx192m in apache tomchat jvm options?

Comment: I have a options , but my prinicpal option is that [RazorEXPLORER](http://www.dailyrazor.com/java-jsp-hosting/private-tomcat-hosting/)
the "RazorEXPLORER" plan

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite answer to this.

The heap size you will need depends on how you implement your web application.  It is not possible to provide estimates based on vague descriptions like the ones that you have given ... or even on really good descriptions.  An application's heap space requirements depend *to a large degree* on how you architect and implement the application.

I advise you to start out small, and if you run into problems either "tune" your system or upgrade to a larger instance.

You could also do some scaling tests on a non-hosted system; e.g. a private desktop or laptop.

---

> Its the same to test in my netbeans the jvm with-Xmx192m in apache tomcat jvm options?

My guess would be yes.

To be sure, you would need to ask the hosting company for details on how they configure Tomcat and its JVM.  There are a number of heap and GC tuning parameters that could impact on this.  (It also depends on whether you are simply interested in avoiding OOMEs ... or in tuning performance more generally.)

Bear in mind that there are other factors that affect performance on a hosting platform, e.g. number of CPUS / VCPUs, memory overcommit, disk & network I/O bandwidth provided.